# ¿Como crear una tabla a partir de inner join usando SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

¿Como crear una tabla a partir de inner join usando SQL?

Esta es mi consulta

```
SELECT c.ID_CLIENTE, dt.NUM_FACTURA , f.NUM_FACTURA  FROM CLIENTES C
INNER JOIN FACTURA F on c.ID_CLIENTE = f.ID_CLIENTE
inner join DETALLE_FACTURA dt on dt.NUM_FACTURA = f.NUM_FACTURA
GROUP BY DT.NUM_FACTURA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT c.ID_CLIENTE, dt.NUM_FACTURA , f.NUM_FACTURA 
INTO TablaNueva 
FROM CLIENTES C
INNER JOIN FACTURA F on c.ID_CLIENTE = f.ID_CLIENTE
inner join DETALLE_FACTURA dt on dt.NUM_FACTURA = f.NUM_FACTURA
GROUP BY DT.NUM_FACTURA
```

Mediante esta consulta especial usando la **cláusula into** creamos una nueva tabla con la estructura definida por los campos del **select**, y esta nueva tabla será poblada por todos los registros devueltos por la consulta, es decir se hacen dos pasos en uno: se crea la tabla con su estructura y se llenan sus campos con la consulta realizada.

Answer (score 1):

Muy sencillo, únicamente agrega esto antes del SELECT

CREATE TABLE NOMBREDETUTABLANUEVA